# Constant differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the procedure for solving a simple differential equation:

$y'(t)=C$, where C is a constant? What is y(t)?

${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Integrate. ${}{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=C\\
\implies \int\mathrm{d}y=C\int \mathrm{d}t\\
\implies y=Ct+A,\text{ $A$ a constant, i.e., $y$ is a linear equation in $t$.}$$
Take the derivative of $y=Ct+A$. $A^\prime=0$, and $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}(Ct)}{\mathrm{d}t}=C$, so $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=C$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $C$ is the constant, we simply get:

$$\begin{aligned}
\int y'(t)\,dt &= \int C\,dt\\
y(t) = Ct + D
\end{aligned}$$

where $D$ is an extra constant.  You can also solve this problem using separation of variable, but there is no extra work needed.